# add token in header of post request to drupal rest api with retrofit android

Tags: android, drupal-7, retrofit

In my project, I have to access restful api provided by drupal7. While accessing api with post request, I have to give token and session id in header of request. I test with (Poster, firefox plugin for testing restful api), and add Cookie and X-CRSF-Token correctly in header section of Poster , server retrun this json "{"status":0,"message":"username already exist! Type another name."}".

[image]

Here is my android code to access the same api request by Poster with the same Cookie and X-CRSF-Token, but server returns "Access denied for user anonymous".

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

```
public void StoreCreateAsync(){
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
    dialog.show();

    final String token = pref.getString(Constants.token,"");
    final String cookie = pref.getString(Constants.session,"");

    //token = "dWGgzRIPAZt9YI48W2DCPny9Fk8WcPh_ifBgdZ5f8x4";
    //cookie = "SESSeef809303b051915f45008580b17a51axQHOT-12m7WHfdU6Xa5vkS3SHfZ5Lhuj3Brgp-uAVyo";

    // for handle socketTimeoutException
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    client.setReadTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    //for header parameter
    //method 1
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Cookie", "SESSeef809303b051915f45008580b17a51axQHOT-12m7WHfdU6Xa5vkS3SHfZ5Lhuj3Brgp-uAVyo");
            request.addHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "dWGgzRIPAZt9YI48W2DCPny9Fk8WcPh_ifBgdZ5f8x4");
        }
    };

    para user_para = new para();
    user_para.storeName = txtName.getText().toString();

    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BaseUrl)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setClient(new OkClient(client))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();

    ApiStoreCreate apiStoreCreate = restAdapter.create(ApiStoreCreate.class);
    apiStoreCreate.postUserStore(user_para,new Callback<obj_store_create>(){

        @Override
        public void success(obj_store_create obj_store_create, Response response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if(response.getStatus() == 200){
               Toast.makeText(mContext, obj_store_create.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               edit.putString(Constants.storeName, obj_store_create.storeName);
               edit.apply();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            response = error.getResponse();
            Log.i(tag, String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
            if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error Status -> "+ response.getStatus() + ". Error -> " + response.getReason() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });



12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): ---> HTTP POST http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/store.json
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): Cookie: SESSeef809303b051915f45008580b17a51axQHOT-12m7WHfdU6Xa5vkS3SHfZ5Lhuj3Brgp-uAVyo
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): X-CSRF-Token: dWGgzRIPAZt9YI48W2DCPny9Fk8WcPh_ifBgdZ5f8x4
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): Content-Length: 26
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): {"storeName":"sawyyyyyuu"}
12-17 11:52:09.950: D/Retrofit(27129): ---> END HTTP (26-byte body)

12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): <--- HTTP 403 http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/store.json (5215ms)
12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 05:22:31 GMT
12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.27
 12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.27
 12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
 12-17 11:52:15.160: D/Retrofit(27129): Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
 12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): Content-Length: 36
 12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
 12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): Connection: Keep-Alive
 12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): Content-Type: application/json
12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1450329730132
12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1450329735171
12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): ["Access denied for user anonymous"]
12-17 11:52:15.170: D/Retrofit(27129): <--- END HTTP (36-byte body)
```

Comment: Is that your api required user-name and password in body of request? If yes are you passing the body in request?

Comment: I already login by sending username and password in the content by json format, after login success server returns cookie and token. In poster I used that cookie and token in header of post request.

Answer (score 0):

I think your api are following OAuth and they know the device type you making the request. So thats why it is not identifying the token you are passing in the request.

If you want to see clear difference between both the request->
1. Request from web
2. Request from Mobile

Use [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/)  it will provide you end point and when you making the request just replace your actual end point with the provided end point by RequestBin.
After execution of your request you can check the fired request with all content like:- headers, body and content-type on RequestBin site do not close the browser after getting end point wait and diagnosis your request their.
You can check where you actually making the mistake.